# How to overwrite UI Component XHTML files in a theme - Recently Viewed

Tags: magento2, layout, template, uicomponent, magento2.2.3

How can I override `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/templates/listing/default.xhtml` in a theme? In this instance it's for the recently viewed products widget.

This is added here - vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition.xml:10

```
<listing sorting="true" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing" component="uiComponent">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/listing/default</item>
        <item name="save_parameters_in_session" xsi:type="string">1</item>
        <item name="client_root" xsi:type="string">mui/index/render</item>
    </argument>
</listing>
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this add the file to your theme excluding `view/base/`.

Like this - `app/design/frontend/StoreName/ThemeName/Magento_Ui/ui_component/templates/listing/default.xhtml`

After flushing cache it works.